# Can I tell when I was given sudo access?

Tags: sudo

I'm on a Centos system.  It was just created.  My account has sudo access.

The person who set up the system had to be reminded to do some basic steps and took a long time.  I'm wondering if giving the admin account sudo access was one of those things or if they figured it out on their own.

So can I tell if this account had sudo access before I mentioned it (I know when I mentioned it)?

Comment: There's no log of this, but you could a hint from timestamps on some master config files.  `/etc/sudoers` might have been changed to give you access.  Alternatively it might already have an entry to allow a particular group.  In which case they might have added you to that group so you could check when `/etc/group` changed.  But there's basically no log of when this changed.

Comment: Ask them? This sounds like a social issue, not a technical one.

Comment: @Kusalananda Asking someone if they're competent at their job is awkward.

Comment: Asking about when some task was carried out doesn't strike me as a question about competency, the task was carried out after all.  In any case, it should be logged (if they used `sudo` to do it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without some external help, such as:

- previous date-stamped versions of `/etc/sudoers`
- a version-control system containing `/etc/sudoers`

The timestamp of `/etc/sudoers` could be a weak signal; if the timestamp closely correlates with your reminder, there's a good chance that it was edited for *your* access at that time, but it's also possible that you previously had access and the coincidental edit was for something/someone else.

Comment: You can also see the first time you successfully `sudo`ed to root by checking your home directory for a zero-byte file with the name `.sudo_as_admin_successful`.

Comment: The timestamp on `/etc/sudoers` (and `/etc/group`) should also tell that access was granted no later than some point in time. If the timestamps are before the reminder, then their access was edited in before that, even though the opposite doesn't hold.

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/sudoers` has a very old date stamp (clearly not changed).

`/etc/group` was changed 6 hours ago.  A diff between that and `/etc/group-` shows my account was added.

The system was supposedly done and ready for me yesterday, so I have an answer.

Thank you everyone.